# Install fabric8 on local kubernetes (non-GCE) cluster

Tags: fabric8

I have a local kubernetes cluster setup from the RHEL7 binaries.

When I attempt to install fabric8 on the cluster into a namespace everything looks good and start up...but, when taking a look at the fabric8 console, I get a "No namespaces available message" (or something to that affect.)  We have port 8080 open locally, and we are also setup for authentication on the secure port 6443.

I did notice that there were a bunch of OAUTH settings which I would guess are more specifically OpenShift or GCE.

Is it even possible to deploy fabric8 into a native kubernetes cluster, or is OpenShift required?  I can't find anything about it.

Comment: I use https://github.com/TheNewNormal/kube-cluster-osx to run it locally it seems to run - but I am just getting started. I installed using `kubectl create -f http://central.maven.org/maven2/io/fabric8/apps/console-kubernetes/2.2.104/console-kubernetes-2.2.104-kubernetes.json` After a while `kubectl get pods
NAME              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
fabric8-nzdqj     1/1       Running   0          7m
templates-llple   1/1       Running   0          7m` both pods are available. but No applications are installed https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/issues/5718

Answer (score 0):

I use fabric8 on kubernetes quite a lot. These days it works great!

Here's the latest instructions on installing it on kubernetes 1.2: http://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/kubernetes.html

There are various other options based on if you want to spin up kubernetes via vagrant or use GKE etc: http://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/index.html